# CSS Pseudo Classes with Article

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm trying to get the first article on the page using CSS. I have tried the following:

```
article:first {
    background: blue;
}
```

and

```
article:first-child {
    background: blue;
}
```

However neither of these seem to be doing anything.

My HTML markup is as follows (head removed and content ellipsed):

```
...
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <hgroup>
                ...
            </hgroup>
        </header>
        <article>
            ...
        </article>
        <article>
            ...
        </article>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'm also using the latest version of chrome.

Comment: There is no :first pseudo-class in CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `#wrapper article:first-of-type`, but unfortunately it's not widely supported yet.

You could try `#wrapper header + article` though, for which support is more widespread.

Comment: Nice that works... I'm not too fussed if its fully supported, I'm only using it for something minor. The site doesn't break if I am unable to style the first article. =D

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your markup:

```
...
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <hgroup>
                ...
            </hgroup>
        </header>
        <section>
            <article>
                ...
            </article>
            <article>
                ...
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
```

`:first-child` works only with *real* first children elements (it was `header` in your case).

Comment: Or just use `:nth-child(2)` (CSS3)